# Creating a click event in Javascript Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm having trouble creating a click event for my Javascript canvas game. So far I have been following a tutorial, however the way you interact with the game is through mouse hover. I would like to change it so that instead of hovering over objects in the canvas to interact, I instead use a mouse click.

The following is the code I use to detect the mouse hover.

```
getDistanceBetweenEntity = function (entity1,entity2) //return distance
{
    var vx = entity1.x - entity2.x;
    var vy = entity1.y - entity2.y;
    return Math.sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy);
}

testCollisionEntity = function (entity1,entity2) //return if colliding
{
    var distance = getDistanceBetweenEntity(entity1,entity2);
    return distance < 50;
}
```

I then use this in a loop to interact with it.

```
    var isColliding = testCollisionEntity(player,nounList[key]);
    if(isColliding)
    {
        delete nounList[key];
        player.score = player.score + 10;

    }
```

Below is a complete copy of my game at its current state.

```
    <canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");

ctx.font = '30px Arial';

//Setting the height of my canvas
var HEIGHT = 500;
var WIDTH = 500;

//Player class
var player = 
{
    x:50,
    spdX:30,
    y:40,
    spdY:5,
    name:'P',
    score:0,
};

//Creating arrays
var nounList ={};
var adjectivesList ={};
var verbsList ={};

getDistanceBetweenEntity = function (entity1,entity2) //return distance
{
    var vx = entity1.x - entity2.x;
    var vy = entity1.y - entity2.y;
    return Math.sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy);
}

testCollisionEntity = function (entity1,entity2) //return if colliding
{
    var distance = getDistanceBetweenEntity(entity1,entity2);
    return distance < 50;
}

Nouns = function (id,x,y,name)
{
    var noun = 
    {
        x:x,
        y:y,
        name:name,
        id:id,
    };
    nounList[id] = noun;
}

Adjectives = function (id,x,y,name)
{
    var adjective = 
    {
        x:x,
        y:y,
        name:name,
        id:id,
    };
    adjectivesList[id] = adjective;
}

Verbs = function (id,x,y,name)
{
    var verb = 
    {
        x:x,
        y:y,
        name:name,
        id:id,
    };
    verbsList[id] = verb;
}


document.onmousemove = function(mouse)
{
    var mouseX = mouse.clientX;
    var mouseY = mouse.clientY;

    player.x = mouseX;
    player.y = mouseY;
}






updateEntity = function (something)
{
    updateEntityPosition(something);
    drawEntity(something);
}

updateEntityPosition = function(something)
{

}

drawEntity = function(something)
{
    ctx.fillText(something.name,something.x,something.y);
}


update = function ()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

    drawEntity(player);

    ctx.fillText("Score: " + player.score,0,30);

    for(var key in nounList)
    {
        updateEntity(nounList[key]);


        var isColliding = testCollisionEntity(player,nounList[key]);
        if(isColliding)
        {
            delete nounList[key];
            player.score = player.score + 10;

        }
    }

    for(var key in adjectivesList)
    {
        updateEntity(adjectivesList[key])
        var isColliding = testCollisionEntity(player,adjectivesList[key]);
        if(isColliding)
        {
            delete adjectivesList[key];
            player.score = player.score - 1;
        }

    }

    for(var key in verbsList)
    {
        updateEntity(verbsList[key])
        var isColliding = testCollisionEntity(player,verbsList[key]);
        if(isColliding)
        {
            delete verbsList[key];
            player.score = player.score - 1;
        }

    }

    if(player.score >= 46)
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        ctx.fillText("Congratulations! You win!",50,250);
        ctx.fillText("Refresh the page to play again.",50,300);
    }

}

Nouns('N1',150,350,'Tea');
Nouns('N2',400,450,'Park');
Nouns('N3',250,150,'Knee');
Nouns('N4',50,450,'Wall');
Nouns('N5',410,50,'Hand');

Adjectives('A1',50,100,'Broken');
Adjectives('A2',410,300,'Noisy');

Verbs('V1',50,250,'Smell');
Verbs('V2',410,200,'Walk');

setInterval(update,40);
```

To summarize all I want to do is change it so that instead of mousing over words to delete them you have to click.

(Apologies for not using correct terminology in places, my programming knowledge is quite limited.)

Comment: What is the problem? Where do you add mouse event listeners?

Comment: Where do the mouse action take part? Please edit your code and add the mouse hover part and it should be simple enough to transform the hover action to click action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your canvas listen for mouse clicks on itself like this:

```
// get a reference to the canvas element
var canvas=document.getElementById('ctx'); 

// tell canvas to listen for clicks and call "handleMouseClick"
canvas.onclick=handleMouseClick;
```

In the click handler, you'll need to know the position of your canvas relative to the viewport. That's because the browser always reports mouse coordinates relative to the viewport. You can get the canvas position relative to the viewport like this:

```
// get the bounding box of the canvas
var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
// get the left X position of the canvas relative to the viewport
var BBoffsetX=BB.left;
// get the top Y position of the canvas relative to the viewport
var BBoffsetY=BB.top;
```

So your `mouseClickHandler` might look like this:

```
// this function will be called when the user clicks
// the mouse in the canvas
function handleMouseClick(e){
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // get the canvas postion relative to the viewport
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var BBoffsetX=BB.left;
    var BBoffsetY=BB.top;            
    // calculate the mouse position
    var mouseX=e.clientX-BBoffsetX;
    var mouseY=e.clientY-BBoffsetY;
    // report the mouse position using the h4
    $position.innerHTML='Click at '+parseInt(mouseX)+' / '+parseInt(mouseY);
}
```

If your game doesn't let the window scroll or resize then the canvas postion won't change relative to the viewport. Then, for better performance, you can move the 3 lines relating to getting the canvas position relative to the viewport to the top of your app.

```
// If the browser window won't be scrolled or resized then
// get the canvas postion relative to the viewport
// once at the top of your app
var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var BBoffsetX=BB.left;
var BBoffsetY=BB.top;            

function handleMouseClick(e){
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // calculate the mouse position
    var mouseX=e.clientX-BBoffsetX;
    var mouseY=e.clientY-BBoffsetY;
    // report the mouse position using the h4
    $position.innerHTML='Click at '+parseInt(mouseX)+' / '+parseInt(mouseY);
}
```